# How to calculate a field in using updatecursor?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I'm trying to simply add a string in front of a group of numbers from another field in a new field.  The filed I'm using update cursor in is GIS_ID_PAM and I'm trying to bring over numbers from a column called PointID.  My intent is to get "PAM - " in front of the numbers from the PointID column.  Here's what I have that isn't working.

```
        urows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)
        for urow in urows:
            urow.DateImport = str(timestr)
            urow.GIS_ID_PAM = "PAM - " + [PointID]
            urows.updateRow(urow)
```

Comment: Is GIS_ID_PAM of field type `Text` or something else?

Comment: If you are using ArcMap >= 10.1, you should investigate the [data access module](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000008000000). Much better cursor support.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If PointID is one of the fields of fc, you can either use

```
urow.GIS_ID_PAM = "PAM - " + str(urow.PointID)
```

or

```
urow.setValue("GIS_ID_PAM", "PAM - " + str(urow.getValue("PointID"))
```

str() is not necessary if your PointID field is already of type "text".

EDIT : example with .format() (based on Paul's comment)

```
urow.setValue("GIS_ID_PAM", "PAM - {0!s}".format(urow.getValue("PointID"))
```

Comment: Instead of using string concatenation, you might want to use `.format()`. It has built in string casting for variables and can be a lot simpler when concatenating strings and variables.